# Is there something I am doing wrong by trying to make a rectangle?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make a rectangle by filling it with html/javascript, but for some reason, even though it's only a few lines of code, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here

I've already tried in the code using strokeStyle and not using the viewport , I also tried using  `var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");`  like this, with double quotes

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 50px; width: 100vw; max-width: 100%;"></canvas>
```

I truly don't know anymore what I'm doing wrong and I just want to make a rectangle

Comment: `rgb(255, 255, 255)` is white, so you get a white rectangle. Try changing the color.

Comment: `HTMLCanvasElement` should have `height` and `width` attributes. Scaling with css is not a good idea.

Comment: Alright thank you , stupid mistake on my side haha

Answer (score 1):

You're drawing a white rectangle on a white canvas.

Change `ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";` to be a color that shows up on a white background:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 50px; width: 100vw; max-width: 100%;"></canvas>
```

Comment: The canvas is not white though, the page's background is.